# Find the nearest value in dataframe column and calculate the difference for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find

Even though I was googling a lot, I couldn't find the solution for my problem.

I have dataframe

```
    filter10    REF
0   NaN         0.00
1   NaN         0.75
2   NaN         1.50
3   NaN         2.25
4   NaN         3.00
5   NaN         3.75
6   NaN         4.50
...
15  2.804688    11.25
16  3.021875    12.00
17  3.578125    12.75
18  3.779688    13.50
...
27  NaN         20.25
28  NaN         21.00
29  NaN         21.75
30  NaN         22.50
31  6.746875    NaN
32  NaN         NaN
...
```

I would like now to add the column  `df['DIFF']` where function goes through whole column `filter10`  and when it is the number it finds closest number in `REF` column.

And afterwards calculate the difference between them and put it the same row as number in `filter10` is.

I would like this output:

```
    filter10    REF     DIFF
0   NaN         0.00    NaN
1   NaN         0.75    NaN
2   NaN         1.50    NaN
3   NaN         2.25    NaN
4   NaN         3.00    NaN
5   NaN         3.75    NaN
6   NaN         4.50    NaN
...
15  2.804688    11.25   -0.195312 # 2.804688 - 3 (find closest value in REF) = -0.195312
16  3.021875    12.00   0.021875
17  3.578125    12.75   -0.171875
18  3.779688    13.50   0.029688
...
27  NaN         20.25   NaN
28  NaN         21.00   NaN
29  NaN         21.75   NaN
30  NaN         22.50   NaN
31  6.746875    NaN     -0.003125
32  NaN         NaN     NaN
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.merge_asof` to find the nearest value:

```
df['DIFF'] = (pd.merge_asof(df['filter10'].dropna().sort_values().reset_index(),
                            df[['REF']].dropna().sort_values('REF'),
                            left_on='filter10', right_on='REF', direction='nearest')
                .set_index('index')['REF'].rsub(df['filter10'])
              )
```

Output:

```
    filter10    REF      DIFF
0        NaN   0.00       NaN
1        NaN   0.75       NaN
2        NaN   1.50       NaN
3        NaN   2.25       NaN
4        NaN   3.00       NaN
5        NaN   3.75       NaN
6        NaN   4.50       NaN
15  2.804688  11.25 -0.195312
16  3.021875  12.00  0.021875
17  3.578125  12.75 -0.171875
18  3.779688  13.50  0.029688
27       NaN  20.25       NaN
28       NaN  21.00       NaN
29       NaN  21.75       NaN
30       NaN  22.50       NaN
31  6.746875    NaN  2.246875 # likely different due to missing data
32       NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, one can use [cKDTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) for this:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s="""    filter10    REF
0   NaN         0.00
1   NaN         0.75
2   NaN         1.50
3   NaN         2.25
4   NaN         3.00
5   NaN         3.75
6   NaN         4.50
15  2.804688    11.25
16  3.021875    12.00
17  3.578125    12.75
18  3.779688    13.50
27  NaN         20.25
28  NaN         21.00
29  NaN         21.75
30  NaN         22.50
31  6.746875    NaN
32  NaN         NaN"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delimiter=r"\s+")

from scipy.spatial import cKDTree # or simply KDTree

tree = cKDTree(df.REF.values[:,None])  # needs to be an nxm array, hence the [:,None] which is called a broadcast in numpy world

df['DIFF'] = df.filter10 - np.array([df.REF[i] if not np.isinf(dist) else np.nan for dist,i in [tree.query(x,1) for x in df.filter10]]) 

#    filter10    REF      DIFF
#0        NaN   0.00       NaN
#1        NaN   0.75       NaN
#2        NaN   1.50       NaN
#3        NaN   2.25       NaN
#4        NaN   3.00       NaN
#5        NaN   3.75       NaN
#6        NaN   4.50       NaN
#15  2.804688  11.25 -0.195312
#16  3.021875  12.00  0.021875
#17  3.578125  12.75 -0.171875
#18  3.779688  13.50  0.029688
#27       NaN  20.25       NaN
#28       NaN  21.00       NaN
#29       NaN  21.75       NaN
#30       NaN  22.50       NaN
#31  6.746875    NaN  2.246875
#32       NaN    NaN       NaN
```

The query method returns infinity when the point in question is `nan`.

Comment: Every time I tried to run this solution, my kernel died ... So, I cannot evaluate it, if it is working.

Comment: weird! You can replace `cKDTree` with simply `KDTree`, e.g. `from scipy.spatial import KDTree` , and try that. Not sure what could be the issue, but KD-trees are highly optimized ways to compute nearest neighbors, and work fine with millions of points...

Comment: I added a complete example just in case.. I posted a very similar answer to a different question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73898746/2077270