# Finding the closest pair (within a tolerance) of tuple from a pandas data frame in O(N) time complexity or better

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, grouping, lookup

The problem I am facing may be realizable in a looping, however, I need to figure out a pythonic solution with max O(N) time complexity:

So the problem is this:

I have a data frame (which I call say lookup) say as follows:(it may be a very big data frame of 100M + rows) ( my A & B are the columns to search and M, N are the values which I will search for and finally col V is which I will extract). So let me be explicit. For the sake of our argument I only show 5 rows:

```
 lookup_df 

    A     B     M      N        V

    a1    b1    2.6   12.7     200.6
    u1    v1    4.5   19       145
    a2    b2    3.2   15.9     100
    a3    b3    5.5   21.5     45
    a7    b7    6.8   41.8     90
    a10   b10   70.0  120.5    123
```

So now the issue is I have another data frame which I call input. So that can have  either the exact A & B column values or may have some new A and B values. So the input do may look like this (say). I show here also 5 rows to show case the point:

```
  input_df 

     A     B     M      N        

     u1   v1     4.5    19
     u1   v1     3.0    16.2
     a3   b3     5.5    21.5 
     a3   x1     7.0    41.5
     x7   y2    69.8   120.1
```

So now the problem to solve is whenever I have exact match of the values in both lookup and input data frames between A, B, M, N , my V column gets the value from lookup as expected. However, for example in second row of input data frame the A & B match but M & N values differ. So the nearest ( 0.3 say is my threshold) is row 3 of lookup table corresponding to V for a2 and b2, so I pick that V. Again a3 and b3 in input exactly matches with lookup for M and N columns, so I can pickup that V. For the last two rows in input , there are no rows in this sample lookup data frame, so I go by the closest values in lookup again, which for a3, x1 happens to be the values in V for a7,b7 and for x7, y2 matches with values for a10, b10.

Thus the output df for my input should look like:

```
 output_df 

     A     B     M      N        V

     u1   v1     4.5    19       145
     u1   v1     3.0    16.2     100
     a3   b3     5.5    21.5      45
     a3   x1     7.0    41.5      90
     x7   y2    69.8   120.1      123
```

So my lookup data frame is enormous (100M +) with having all possible combination.My input data frame may not be that large, maybe 10000 rows, however, let’s say I use a threshold of 0.3 to find the nearest pair, how can I have an efficient search code to scan through the lookup to get my output as desired.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get `O(N)` here.

Comment: Thank you @AKX. Any algorithm to efficiently in Python even if mot O(N)?

Comment: If you have two "coordinates" (M, N), as it were, you might be looking for some sort of spatial lookup structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index

Comment: @Stan, check Quang Hoang's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73896664/16120011.

Comment: @Stan The tolerance `0.3` applies only to column `M`?

Comment: Hello @AndrejKesely: Thank you ideally we apply 0.3 tolerance to both M and N, nut if its only one columns, say is there something we can do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the merges into several steps:

##### 1. Try to find exact merges

```
exact_matches = pd.merge(input_df, lookup_df, on=["A", "B", "M", "N"])
print(exact_matches)
```

Prints:

```
    A   B    M     N      V
0  u1  v1  4.5  19.0  145.0
1  a3  b3  5.5  21.5   45.0
```

---

##### 2. Exclude exact matches from `input_df`

```
# exclude exact matches from input_df
input_df = input_df.loc[~input_df.index.isin(exact_matches.index)]
```

##### 3. Merge by `M`

```py
# merge M
lookup_df = lookup_df.sort_values(by="M")
input_df = input_df.sort_values(by="M")

M_V = pd.merge_asof(
    input_df, lookup_df[["M", "V"]], on="M", direction="nearest", tolerance=0.3
)[["A", "B", "M", "N", "V"]]
```

##### 4. Merge by `N`

```
# merge N
lookup_df = lookup_df.sort_values(by="N")
input_df = input_df.sort_values(by="N")

N_V = pd.merge_asof(
    input_df, lookup_df[["N", "V"]], on="N", direction="nearest", tolerance=0.3
)[["V"]]

vals = pd.concat([M_V, N_V[["V"]].add_suffix("_2")], axis=1)
print(vals)
```

This prints:

```
    A   B     M      N      V   V_2
0  a3  b3   5.5   21.5   45.0  45.0
1  a3  x1   7.0   41.5   90.0  90.0
2  x7  y2  69.8  120.1  123.0   NaN
```

---

##### 4. Combine exact matches and tolerance matches together

But here you must specify the logic (what if the values of `V`/`V_2` are different? etc.) Now I simply concatenate them:

```
print(pd.concat([exact_matches, vals]))
```

Prints:

```
    A   B     M      N      V   V_2
0  u1  v1   4.5   19.0  145.0   NaN
1  a3  b3   5.5   21.5   45.0   NaN
0  a3  b3   5.5   21.5   45.0  45.0
1  a3  x1   7.0   41.5   90.0  90.0
2  x7  y2  69.8  120.1  123.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely. I will implement and keep you posted.